# java.lang.NullPointerException in Jmeter test execution

Tags: jmeter

When I am running test JMeter getting below error:

> {"id":460979218,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"errorEnum":{"code":-32603,"severity":"err"},"stackTrace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat
>   com.jda.common.pivot.broker.actions.AbstractAction.getResponse

Could any one guide me what could be the reason for prompt `java.lang.NullPointerException` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your server expects some value which must be present in the request and JMeter fails to provide the value.

There could be different reasons for this, one of possible ones is that you don't provide the relevant [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) so the server is not able to parse the value even if it's present in the request body.